# Python character function, where is the "Z"?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to convert numbers to excel column letters.

Code:

```
def num2col(num):
    letters = ''
    while num:
        mod = num % 26
        num = num // 26
        letters += chr(mod + 64)
    return ''.join(reversed(letters))

print num2col(25), num2col(26), num2col(27)    
print num2col(51), num2col(52), num2col(53)
print num2col(77), num2col(78), num2col(79)
```

Desired output:

```
Y Z AA
AY AZ BA
BY BZ CA
```

Actual output:

```
Y A@ AA
AY B@ BA
BY C@ CA
```

Comment: Try `letters += chr(mod + 65)` instead of `letters += chr(mod + 64)`

Comment: nope. output: `Z BA BB
BZ CA CB
CZ DA DB`

Comment: Try `mod = mod if mod > 0 else 26` right after `mod = num % 26` (and forget the last thing I said)

Comment: If you're trying to convert numbers to Excel column labels, shouldn't the one after `Y` be `Z`?

Comment: Do you mean `Y Z AA`, `AY AZ BA`, `BY BZ CA` ?

Comment: you are absolutely right. typo. thanks for the correction.

Comment: 26 mod 26 is 0.  ASCII 64 is @.  If A=1, you're not going to get a Z from your loop.  Try 65 + ((num - 1) % 26)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def num2col(num):
    letters = ''
    while num:
        num, mod = divmod(num-1, 26)
        letters += chr(mod + 65)      # 65 == ord('A')
    return ''.join(reversed(letters))

print num2col(25), num2col(26), num2col(27)    
print num2col(51), num2col(52), num2col(53)
print num2col(77), num2col(78), num2col(79)
```

output:

```
Y Z AA
AY AZ BA
BY BZ CA
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I've used my original code for years, some how by luck column letter ending in 'Z' never showed up... til now...